# CodeIgniter redirect not working?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Ok I have a controller named Login and have an index() function that displays the view user/login. I build the urls with user/login, but with the redirect, I'm doing this:

`redirect('/user/login/');`

But I've also tried `redirect('/login/');`
How comes my login won't load? It keeps giving me a 404 error...

I've also tried `('/login/index')` and `('/login')`

Comment: Do you have a controller class named "user" or "login"?

Comment: /user/login/ means controller called user and action called login.

Comment: I have a controller named Login with a method index()

Comment: I just put redirect('/login/index/') or just redirect('/login/') and none of them works!

Comment: Did you try to access any of these URL directly in your browser?  Did it works?

Comment: This works: http://dstable.localhost/login It's the login controller and index() method, but the redirect wont work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have only one controller, `Login`, with only one page, `index`, in it, so why do you need a redirect? Are you just trying to get your index page to show your login view? If so you do that with something like:

```
$this->load->view('path/to/view');
```

Comment: No it's when they reset their password, I want it to redirect them to the login page after it sends the email.. so I need a redirect!

Answer (score 0):

you can try `redirect(site_url("login"));`, if you haven't changed the relevant routing in your CI install it will take you to the `login` controller (and the index() method by default)

edit: I misread the question

Answer (score 0):

Ah.. sorry, my bad. I have an if statement that isn't even letting it get to the redirect part... I'm sorry!